# Can feature layer in MXD with joined data from non-geodatabase be published as feature service?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, feature-service

I have a table stored in an SDE geodatabase for all point features with an additional GEOMETRY_ID. A few non-spatial data tables are stored in an ordinary MS SQL Server database. They can be joined by the common GEOMETRY_ID and the layer is stored in a MXD.

The MXD file couldn't be published as feature service, so Add, Update and Delete operations cannot be applied to this layer. Therefore, I am planning to move the non-spatial database to SDE geodatabase and published as feature service.

I have questions as below:

1. Is that true that a feature layer in MXD that has joined data from non-geo database cannot be published as feature service in ArcGIS Server?
2. In order to allow operations to those non-spatial tables, say Add, Update and Delete records, is it a good practise to store them into SDE geodatabase and published as feature service?